# jquery failed updating image attribute on firefox

Tags: jquery, image, attributes

I have the following code

```
var first = $jq("<div></div>");
first.append("<td><img id='smile' src='/Images/smile.png' style='width: 120px; height: 120px; display: none; padding-top: 5px; padding-right: 5px;' alt='image' /></td>");

// some logic ...

var img = $jq('#smile');
img[0].style.display = 'inline';
```

The code works perfectly fine on IE (9), but not on FF (tried on 7.0). Any reasons? And if possible, work around?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using $jq("#smile").css("display", "inline"); ?

Comment: Adding onto @AndrewKoester's comment i'd also do `first.find("#smile").css("display", "inline");`. I'd put that into an answer if I were you Andrew.

Comment: .css('display', 'inline'); as a workaround?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
img.css("display", "inline");
```

http://api.jquery.com/css/